# JavaScript forEach loop retrieve items that aren't the current element

Tags: javascript, foreach

Right, this is going to sound silly and I'm not sure if I'm a moment but I have a group of buttons on a page and the aim is for me to click each one, the button disappears and is replaced with a text box. Then when another one is clicked, all over text boxes revert to the button.

I have tried using a foreach loop by targeting only the index and changing the rest but I don't think that's the right way to go about it. Is there a better, more concise way of doing it?

```
buttons.forEach((button, buttonIndex) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        popups.forEach((popup, popupIndex) => {
            if (buttonIndex == popupIndex) {
                popup.style.display = 'inline-grid';
                button.style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                popup.style.display = 'none';
                button.style.display = 'inline-grid';
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please add any relevant JavaScript code/HTML markup/CSS to your question as a [mcve]. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you. You should explain in a little more detail what "all over text boxes revert to the button" means.

Comment: Does your code work? If yes, then SO is not the right place for this question. Ask it at [codereview.se] instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of toggling the display property for each popup and button individually, we can simply assign the appropriate value based on the comparison between buttonIndex and popupIndex. If they are equal, the popup's display is set to 'inline-grid'; otherwise, it is set to 'none'.

After the loop, we hide the clicked button by setting its display to 'none'.

This code achieves the same result as your original code but in a more concise manner.

```
buttons.forEach((button, buttonIndex) => {
      button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        popups.forEach((popup, popupIndex) => {
          popup.style.display = (buttonIndex === popupIndex) ? 'inline-grid' : 'none';
        });
        button.style.display = 'none';
      });
});
```

Comment: I guess using this logic then, I can make the button reappear when the buttonIndex isn't equal to the popupIndex right?